# Cancel image or button on the top of the view android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image]

Hi,
   I am trying to create Cancel button on top of the view like in above image.while scroll also image should be still. i have used Floating button.Cancel image is coming as normal but floating round background still coming in the background.i want to remove it.how to remove it or any other way to do it.

Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.ProductDetailsSingleActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cancel_image"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:rippleColor="@null"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/cancel1" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cancel_image">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:layout_margin="10dp"
             android:layout_width="300dp"
             android:layout_height="200dp"
             android:src="@drawable/con_pump5"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_album_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ll_media_count"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rupees"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Rs.12,00,000"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/album_media_label"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:text="media"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/outline_favorite_border_black_18" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/decription"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:text="Silos for selling with good condi.."
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/location2"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/location"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:text="Bangalore,Karnataka"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_album_info"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/des_linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_line"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description :"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/des"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_line2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/des_linear"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_line2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Details :"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/last_linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

            android:layout_below="@+id/detail_linear"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_FeeType"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/company_name"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_name_Val"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/company_name1"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_FeeAmount"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/contact_person"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_class_Val"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/contact_person1"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_reg_no"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/mobile_no"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_reg_Val"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/mobile_no1"
                    android:textSize="15sp"

                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_class_teacher"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/landline_no"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_class_teacher_Val"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/landline_no"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_birth_date"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/address"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_birth_date_Val"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/address1"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_address"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/location"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_address_Val"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/location1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/model_of_year"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/model_of_year1"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/serial_number"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/serial_number1"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/new_machine_cost"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/new_machine_cost1"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/expecting_cost"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/expecting_cost1"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/comments"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/comments1"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

  <Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
     android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
     android:layout_below="@+id/last_linear"
     android:text="CHAT"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: why you are using a floating action button? You can use a normal button and set align parent top attribute as true. So it will be always at the top.

Comment: but it will scroll when scroll the page. i want not to scroll

Comment: It will not scroll  if you are adding  android:layout_below="@+id/cancel_image" in Scrollview

Comment: Then, it will not be like floating .you can see Whiteview Space behind it

Comment: Then do like this way: First, add the Scroll view in the parent layout with attribute align parent top as true. Then below Scrollview, you can add the cancel button also have attribute align parent top as true.

Comment: yes below scroll view  is working.Thank you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this way: First, add the Scroll view in the parent layout with attribute align parent top as true. Then below Scrollview, you can add the cancel button also have attribute align parent top as true.